# Catchable fatal error Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, domdocument

I am lost with this error:

> Catchable fatal error Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 require_once('includes/mysqlConnect.php');
 require_once('includes/utility.php');

 //calling utility
 $utility = new Utility();

 //Creating a connection 
 $connection= new mySQL(); 
 $connection->connect();

 $getContent= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
 //echo $getContent; 

 //create a new DOMDocument Object
 $doc= new DOMDocument(); 

 //load HTML into DOMDoc
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($getContent);
$utility->removeElementsByTagName('script', $doc);
$utility->removeElementsByTagName('style', $doc);
$utility->removeElementsByTagName('link', $doc);
echo  $doc->saveHTML();

//Insert HTMl to DB 
try
{   
       $result=$connection->db_query("CALL finalaggregator.insert_html('$doc')");
       if ($result==0){
           echo "<span style='color:red;'>Error! Data Saving Processes Unsuccessful</span>";
       }
       else {
           echo "<span style='color:green;'>Data Successfully Saved!</span>";
       }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo "<span color='color:red;'>Error in Storing Data! Please Check Store Procedure.</span>";
}


?>
```

But always end up with showing

> DOM Document could not be converted to string on line 29

I want to store the the value of $doc into a database.

When I am trying to to call the stored procedure from Mysql:

```
call finalaggregator.insert_html("<p>Testing123</p>");
```

it is working fine.

Please help me. I am new to php.

My stored procedure is as follow:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_html`( IN HTML LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO finalaggregator.site_html (html) VALUES(HTML); 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply use the instance of `DOMDocument` as a string in your query. You have to explicitly convert it to an HTML string first:

```
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
$result = $connection->db_query("CALL finalaggregator.insert_html('$html')");
```

Comment: it doesn't show original error but goes to "Error! Data Saving Processes Unsuccessful". Can i know why?

Comment: use error_reporting() to know what is the error and it shows "22527".Can i know how to solve this?

Comment: The value `22527` returned from `error_reporting()` is a BitMask, representing the error reporting level. In this case, it is representing `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`, so all errors are displayed execpt for `E_DEPRECATED` and `E_STRICT` (which is not included in `E_ALL`).